# Can I legally use a struct with overloaded operator() as Compare for std::upper_bound?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, language-lawyer

I have structs like this (types simplified to carry over the point), living in a `std::vector`:

```
struct Region {
    int first;
    int count;
    struct Metadata region_metadata;
};
```

In the vector, they are ordered by `first`. If you add `first` and `count`, you get the `first` of the next region; so basically this vector of structs describes metadata for contiguous ranges of numbers.

Now given an integer, I want to look up the metadata. As the regions are sorted, I can use `std::upper_bound`. I implemented it this way:

```
struct Comp
{
    inline bool operator()(const Region &region, int index) const
    {
        return region.first < index;
    }

    inline bool operator()(int index, const Region &region) const
    {
        return index < region.first;
    }
};
```

This works, when calling `std::upper_bound` with:

```
auto iter = std::upper_bound(m_regions.begin(),
                             m_regions.end(),
                             index,
                             Comp());
```

Now this happens to work, because `upper_bound` can internally pick the overload which matches its requirements, as it calls both `Comp()(Region, int)` and `Comp()(int, Region)` (which is the reason why a `[](const Region &reg, int index){…}` would not work).

I actually came up with the solution by tracing down the error messages when using the lambda I mentioned before. The [docs for std::upper_bound at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) write about the fourth argument:

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the
>   requirements of Compare) which returns *​true* if the first argument is
>   less than the second.
>
> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the
>   following:
>
> ```
> bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
> ```
>
> <s>The signature does not need to have `const &`, but the function object
>   must not modify the objects passed to it. The types `Type1` and `Type2`
>   must be such that an object of type `T` can be implicitly converted to
>   both `Type1` and `Type2`, and an object of type `ForwardIt` can be
>   dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both `Type1` and `Type2`.</s>
>
> The type `Type1` must be such that an object of type `T` can be 
>   implicitly converted to `Type1`. The type `Type2` must be such that an 
>   object of type `ForwardIt` can be dereferenced and then implicitly 
>   converted to `Type2`. ​

(cppreference [has been fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp%2Falgorithm%2Fupper_bound&action=historysubmit&diff=84047&oldid=77487) since I posted this question, thanks @T.C.)

Here, `T` is the third argument to `std::upper_bound` and `ForwardIt` is the type of the first two arguments. This quote does not talk about the function object actually being a struct which overloads its `operator()` to cover the "forward" and "reverse" situations.

So in Rules-As-Written, is this legal, or is it an artifact of my specific compiler/standard library combination (g++ 5.3.1)?

I am interested in answers specific to C++14 or C++17.

Full example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


struct Region {
    Region(int first, int count, int n):
        first(first),
        count(count),
        n(n)
    {

    }

    int first;
    int count;
    int n; // think struct Metadata
};


struct Comp
{
    inline bool operator()(const Region &region, int index) const
    {
        return region.first < index;
    }

    inline bool operator()(int index, const Region &region) const
    {
        return index < region.first;
    }
};


int main() {
    std::vector<Region> regions;
    regions.emplace_back(0, 10, 1);
    regions.emplace_back(10, 10, 2);
    regions.emplace_back(20, 10, 3);

    const int lookup = 10;

    auto iter = std::upper_bound(
        regions.begin(),
        regions.end(),
        lookup,
        Comp());

    // yes, I omitted error checking here, with error being iter == regions.begin()
    std::cout << lookup << " is in region with n = " << (iter-1)->n << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ah, @T.C., that also explains my confusion :-). Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Now this happens to work, because `upper_bound` can internally pick the
>   overload which matches its requirements, as it calls both
>   `Comp()(Region, int)` and `Comp()(int, Region)` (which is the reason why a `[](const Region &reg, int index){…}` would not work).

No, `upper_bound` only calls `Comp`'s second overload. That's precisely what your (fixed - thanks @T.C.!) quote is about: The first argument to the comparator is always the  third argument to `upper_bound`. The lambda's parameters should be swapped.

Overloading `operator()` inside a comparator for `upper_bound`/`lower_bound` is inherently meaningless, because only one overload will ever be picked by those algorithms.

`operator()` should be overloaded as you've shown when working with `equal_range`, and it is legal to do so since the internal details of a comparator (or any functor for that matter) are irrelevant to the library: You solely need to make sure that the ordering is strict (i.e. correct semantics) and the overloads unambiguous.

Comment: You are very right. Which might make this question off-topic. I messed up the arguments of the lambda and assumed that they were correct, so I added the overload, which of course made it work. But as my assumption was incorrect, the conclusion was too; it would have worked (and indeed does work) wtih just the (int, Region) overload.

Comment: the question kinda remains. can we rely on overload-resolution for algorithm functors, ie *should* this work for `equal_range`

Comment: @sp2danny Fair enough.